# How to debug WCF service with Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, debugging, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I have two solutions, one is the WCF service and the other one is the Silverlight.
I would like to use the debugger on both solutions at the same time. The debugger for the WCF service automatically starts a ASP.NET development server. However, I have a hard time making my Silverlight client connecting to the ASP.NET development server. The error says that I'm lacking of the client domain policy file.

Ｄｏｅｓ　ａｎｙｏｎｅ　ｋｎｏｗ　ｗｈｅｒｅ　ｓｈｏｕｌｄ　Ｉ　ｐｕｔ　ｔｈｅ　clientaccesspolicy.xml　ｆｏｒ　ｔｈｅ　ASP.NET development server?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at [this blog entry](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/09/silverlight-cannot-access-web-service.aspx) by Tim Heuer which I found helpful in solving the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

clientaccesspolicy.xml needs to be in the root directory for the web server running the WCF service. In your case, this probably means the solution directory for the WCF application (if you're running the web server "in place").

You could also try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) or [Firebug](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.getfirebug.com%2F&ei=mMdITO-4MIHUtQOvr7FJ&usg=AFQjCNFBkks4lrZpbnqiN8-uAnYIvmcCJw) to determine exactly where the file is being requested.

Comment: I used the Firebug and check where the file is being requested. However, I found this address "http://localhost:54286/clientaccesspolicy.xml" which I have no clue to know the physical path that this link points to. The response is 404 not found. I tried to put the policy file in every possible location in my solution but it still cannot find it. Do you have other ideas?
Thanks a lot.